# String concatenation in UNIX / shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shebang

The below code is working fine till the concatenation(second last step) - I need to concatenate Hello to the "physId"
e.g. - The filename is UM123456789.20150503 - i am extracting M123456789 and i need to append ***"HELO"*** to it at the end. But as per the below script - when i am using the concatenation, it is overwriting the M123456789 and the output thus becomes ***HELO456789***. I am trying to get the output as - ***M123456789HELO*** - where am i going wrong?

```
#!bin/sh  
absolutePath=/abc/data/abc_unix/stg/decrypt/*.*  
filepath=$(echo ${absolutePath%.*})  
echo "$filepath"  
filenameext=$(echo ${filepath#/abc*decrypt/})  
echo "$filenameext"  
file=$(echo ${filenameext#.*})  
echo "$file"  
extract_physId=$(echo ${file:1:9})  
physId=$(echo ${extract_physId})  
echo "$physId"  
key="$physId"HELO  
echo "$key"
```

Answer (score 3):

The beginning of the string is being overwritten by HELO because the string ends with a carriage return. Run `dos2unix` on your input files, or `sed 's/\r$//'`

---

BTW, you have a lot of unnecessary `echo`s in there. I would offer a rewrite:

```
#!bin/sh  
for file in /abc/data/abc_unix/stg/decrypt/*.*; do
    filename=$(basename "$file")   # remove the directory
    filename=${filename%.*}        # remove the extension
    physId=${filename#?}           # remove the first char
    key="${physId}HELO"
    echo "$key"
done
```

Comment: how exactly should i be using - sed 's/\r$//' ? - which line?

Comment: need some help on this pls

Comment: `physId=$( echo $extract_physId | tr -d \\r )`

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\r$//' script.sh`, then run it again.

Comment: Thanks so much !! it works!! - but looks like i hv to run it everytime i run the script? - can i include this in the script and just call the script ?

Comment: Nope, just once will do. Did you edit this script on Windows and transfer it to unix?

Comment: no! - i am doing everything on UNIX server - i just closed the terminal - and ran the script again - it didnt work actually! - gives the same old output - HELO456789

Comment: run you script, and pipe the output through `od -c` -- you'll see a `\r` character. Try to figure out how it's getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Either change `#!/bin/sh`  to `#!/bin/bash` or:

change

```
extract_physId=$(echo ${file:1:9})
```

to

```
extract_physId=$( echo "${file}" | cut -c1-10)
```

**sh** don't recognize `${file:1:9}`

Comment: it works in .sh - tell me about the concatenation if you can!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the concatenation. Run this code snippet to check: `#!/bin/sh
string="Hello"
concat="$string"World
echo $concat`

Comment: Have you noticed you misspelled `#!bin/sh`. it's `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: `/bin/sh` *may or may not* be the same shell as `/bin/bash`. If you're using bash-specific features, and if you care about your script's portability to systems where `/bin/sh` might be some non-Bash shell, you should use `#!/bin/bash`.